# JavaScript: toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, internationalization, number-formatting

My JavaScript `toLocaleString()` is doing something strange here. If I have a number less than 1000, it will give dot as decimal delimiter, but if I have a number more than 1000, it will give me comma as decimal delimiter.

My locale setting uses dot as thousand delimiter and comma as decimal delimiter.

This is how I use the code:

```
sellingPrice.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }
```

If sellingPrice is `700`, it will give me `700.00`
If sellingPrice is `7000`, it will give me `7.000,00`

But the result is the same

Why is this happening?

Comment: [Looks good to me.](https://i.imgur.com/aD0i5Gj.png)
Check your Chrome's locales. `window.navigator.language`

Comment: For both `7000` and `700`, this returns `7.000,00` and `700,00` respectively ~ `number.toLocaleString('de', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})`

Comment: How do I exactly setting the format? What setting will javascript follow?

Comment: @Phil mentioned, its because your locale is not set correctly. Use `number.toLocaleString('en', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})` and it should work fine.

Comment: If you want `locale` to be dynamic, use what @mallendeo mentioned...something like `number.toLocaleString(window.navigator.language, {minimumFractionDigits: 2})`

Comment: The reason 700 and 7000 give me different result was because there is a code `parseFloat()` which try to parse a number that is not in `en-us` locale, that is why the result was incorrect. I changed it into `parseFloat(num.replace(',','.')`

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that javascript is following the browser locale.

In my case I use chrome. I have to change the language to my language (Indonesia) to achieve my goal, which is a bit disappointing. I want my browser language to be English.

I cannot use "en" or "de" because I want the code to be dynamic and follows the user locale.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sellingPrice=700;sellingPrice.toLocaleString('en-us', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

will give you the result `700.00`

and

```
var sellingPrice=7000;sellingPrice.toLocaleString('en-us', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

will give you the result `7,000.00`